# Connect to MSSQL database with Ruby

Tags: ruby, sql-server, odbc, dbi

Hi I'm trying to connect to MS SQL database via DBI gem.

I've installed dbi and dbd-odbc gems.
I've set up ODBC driver (System DSN) as 'MYDSN'

While executing the command:

```
require 'dbi'    
mydb = DBI.connect('dbi:ODBC:MYDSN', 'user', 'password')
```

I'm getting this error:

```
DBI::InterfaceError: Unable to load driver 'ODBC' (underlying error: uninitialized constant DBI::DBD::ODBC)
```

What is the issue?

Thank you.

Comment: You don't say if you're on windows or linux/osx, but if the latter, TinyTds just worked for me.  It requires FreeTDS, but none of it's configuration.  https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds

Comment: Hi, I'm running Windows 7, 32 bit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I resolved this issue by installing gem ruby-odbc

```
gem install ruby-odbc
```

Somehow it worked, connection established and now I can work with database.

Comment: gosh, thank you so much - i've been searching for this answer for two months after a windows update burned a machine we were using and killed a legacy application